# Camel File Aggregation Issue

Tags: apache-camel, activemq-classic

Details:  Apache ActiveMQ 5.9.1, Apache Camel 2.15

I have a Camel route which calls a batch process, then that batch id is fed into this route, see below, and split using a multicast.  Each foo(N) route then executes some SQL and marshal's it into CSV.  The aggregate of the routes is then fed into a file aggregator, which zips up the files.

What have I found so far; Camel 2.13 does not support using the camel file name in the header, therefore I upgraded to 2.15.  If I take out all those foo(N) routes that may return an empty result set the process works fine, but that's not an option. If I print the contents of each foo(N) route I do get a list of files to generate, even the ones with zero contents.

**So... where does that leave me? Stuck!
Can someone explain what I'm missing, or something I'm not seeing correctly?**

*Here is my Camel Route definition.*

```
<route>
   <from uri="{{foo.cron.trigger.uri}}"/>
   <setHeader headerName="unique-foo-Id">
    <ognl>new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss").format(request.headers.scheduledFireTime)</ognl>
  </setHeader>
  <multicast parallelProcessing="true" stopOnException="true">
    <to uri="direct:foo1"/>
    <to uri="direct:foo2"/>
    <to uri="direct:foo3"/>
    <to uri="direct:foo4"/>
  </multicast>
</route>

<!-- each foo(N) route looks similar with different SQL -->
<route>
   <from uri="direct:foo1"/>
   <setHeader headerName="CamelFileName">
     <constant>foo1.csv</constant>
   </setHeader>
   <to uri="sql:{{my.foo1.sql}}"/>
   <marshal>
     <csv/>
   </marshal>
   <to uri="direct:foo-aggregate-files"/>
</route>

<route>
  <from uri="direct:foo-aggregate-files" />
  <aggregate strategyRef="fileAggregatorStrategy" strategyMethodAllowNull="true" completionSize="4" forceCompletionOnStop="true">
    <correlationExpression>
      <simple>header.unique-foo-Id</simple>
    </correlationExpression>
    <setHeader headerName="CamelFileName">
      <constant>fooOutbound.zip</constant>
    </setHeader>
    <to uri="file:{{foo.output.folder}}"/>
  </aggregate>
</route>
```

Comment: I am not quit sure I understand. So in your foo(n) routes, if your sql call returns empty, are you saying that the aggregate-files route is not called?

Comment: That is correct. I either it doesn't route to aggregate-files or it fails.  Either way it just hangs.  If I look at mission control, i see there is a waiting thread.  If I comment out the route that returns zero results, everything works fine.

Comment: I did find this message in the logs "Message: [Body is null]" i'm not sure if this has anything do with the completion of the aggregate.

Comment: have you tried setting this parameter? I found it in the doc.. consumer.routeEmptyResultSet. By default it is false. "Whether to route a single empty Exchange if there was no data to poll."

Comment: http://camel.apache.org/sql-component.html

Comment: I saw that parameter, but how does it get set?

Comment: Set it in your to uri for sql.

Comment: I figured out how to add the routeEmptyResultSet to the sql component.  That seems to work for the first call, but on subsequent calls into the route it hangs on the aggregation.  Shutting down also is hanging, I'm finding myself killing the process.  Any thoughts?

Comment: 2015-12-11 09:34:07,701 | [ActiveMQ ShutdownHook] | DEBUG | Still waiting for shutdown of 1 message listener invokers | org.apache.camel.component.jms.DefaultJmsMessageListenerContainer | ActiveMQ ShutdownHook